# REGEX: GETTING VALUE OF href="" EXCEPT FOR PATICULAR STRING

Tags: java, html, regex

Here's my regex code:

```
\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*(\"(([^\"]*\")|'[^']*'|([^'\">\\s]+)))
```

Actually the real problem is like this. I want to change the value for each `href` that will match except for these two types `<link href="foo.css">` and `<link href="boo.ico">`. I want to retain the value of these two `String`s.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(HTML_A_HREF);
Matcher m = p.matcher(getLine());    
setNewLine(m.replaceAll((String.format("%-1s", sp))+"href=\"javascript:history.go(0)\"" + (String.format("%-1s", sp))));
```

`getLine()` is the html file itself.

```
String sp = "";
```

Comment: Hm, could you give more context please? When i put your regex in tool `whatever` it nicely catches the two targeted strings embedded in `<a href="foo.css">yes</a><a href="bar.ico"/>`. Maybe the function/method call or logic does not use the matches perfectly?

Comment: actually the real problem is like this. i want to change the value for each href that will match.. except for this two types.. <link href="foo.css"> <link href="boo.ico"> i want to retain the value of these two Strings

Comment: Thank you for the further info. Best might be to put this into the question (you can always edit it) and provide a short snippet(java, right?) where you use this pattern. Would that be possible? Otherwise I could only offer wild guesses, like: Check the logic, that tries to exclude these matches from the other ones. What is the pattern to identify "all" candidates where you then "subtract" these unwanted ones? So providing a bit of the flow (or the main function/method calls would help a lot IMO.

Comment: i want to catch everything inside the href value and change it to the value i want... except for the .css and .ico value string.

Comment: Pattern p = Pattern.compile(HTML_A_HREF);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(getLine());
  setNewLine(m.replaceAll((String.format("%-1s", sp))+"href=\"javascript:history.go(0)\"" + (String.format("%-1s", sp))));


getline is the html file itself.

Comment: Now if you put this context info into the question text and format it readable I am sure someone can help easily ;-) My java fingers are a bit rusty: Where do you tell the matcher to match all and where get these excluding matches activated? I mean, that I do not spot where you hook the exclude me matches into. Thanks. Sorry if this sounds un-java-ish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex is off. To show you, let me explode it:

```
\\s*(?i)href\\s*=\\s*
(\"
  (
    ([^\"]*\")
    |
    '[^']*'
    |
    ([^'\">\\s]+)
  )
)
```

The leading double-quote is outside the multi-choice block. It needs to be in the first choice section.

Also:

- You should put `(?i)` first.
- With `\"` inside first choice, one set of parenthesis goes away.
- You don't need parenthesis in choice sections.
- Parenthesis around choice block should be non-capturing.

So, that means:

```
(?i)\\s*href\\s*=\\s*
(?:
  \"[^\"]*\"
  |
  '[^']*'
  |
  [^'\">\\s]+
)
```

Which is `(?i)\\s*href\\s*=\\s*(?:\"[^\"]*\"|'[^']*'|[^'\">\\s]+)`.

---

As for the replacement code:

```
String sp = "";
m.replaceAll((String.format("%-1s", sp))
             +
             "href=\"javascript:history.go(0)\""
             +
             (String.format("%-1s", sp))
            )
```

What is the purpose of `(String.format("%-1s", sp))` when `sp = ""`??? An empty string, formatted to fit at least 1 space, left-aligned. That is a single space, i.e. `" "`, so why all that overhead?

```
m.replaceAll(" href=\"javascript:history.go(0)\" ")
```

---

Finally, you want to exclude `foo.css` and `boo.ico`.

One way to do that is with a negative lookahead. Since you have 3 choices, you need to repeat it 3 times:

```
(?i)\\s*href\\s*=\\s*
(?:
  \"(?!foo\\.css|boo\\.ico)[^\"]*\"
  |
  '(?!foo\\.css|boo\\.ico)[^']*'
  |
  (?!foo\\.css|boo\\.ico)[^'\">\\s]+
)
```

I'll let you collapse that back to one line.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to exclude all `.css` and `.ico` files, use a negative lookbehind instead.

Also, I forgot to escape the `.` before, sorry. Fixed that.

```
(?i)\\s*href\\s*=\\s*
(?:
  \"[^\"]*(?<!\\.css|\\.ico)\"
  |
  '[^']*(?<!\\.css|\\.ico)'
  |
  [^'\">\\s]+(?<!\\.css|\\.ico)
)
```